# Representing the principal genus with prime ideals

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals, prime-factorization, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $K$ be a real quadratic number field. For an fractional ideal $\mathfrak a$ we denote with $[\mathfrak a]$ its narrow ideal class. Recall that $[\mathfrak a]=[\mathfrak b]$ holds if and only if there is a $\lambda \in K^\times$ with $\lambda \mathfrak a = \mathfrak b$ and $N(\lambda)>0$ (the norm condition makes the ideal class *narrow*).

Let $\mathfrak a$ be a fixed ideal belonging to the principal genus (i.e. $\mathfrak a= \lambda \mathfrak b^2$ for $\lambda \in K^\times$ with $N(\lambda)>0$ and a fractional ideal $\mathfrak b$). Are there infinitely many prime ideals $\mathfrak p \subset \mathcal O_K$ with $[\mathfrak a]=[\mathfrak p^2]$?

Comment: Why would $\mathfrak{b}^2$ be in the principal genus?

Comment: @reuns By the definition of genus. Don't confuse it with the ideal class.

Comment: What is the definition of genus? And Chebotarev says that there are infinitely many primes of each (generalized, ie. those in class field theory) ideal class.

Comment: The result of Chebotarev is too loose to answer my question. The genus group is defined as $\mathcal{Cl}^+/\operatorname{Sq}^+(\mathcal{Cl}^+)$. The elements of the group are the genera. If $t$ is the number of distict prime divisors of the discriminant $D_K$, then the genus group has cardinality $2^{t-1}$.

Comment: There are infinitely many primes in the same narrow class as $\mathfrak{b}$, whose square will be in the same narrow class as $\mathfrak{a}$.

Comment: I say Chebotarev but all you need is that for a non-trivial Hecke character $L(s,\psi)$ is analytic and non-zero at $s=1$.

Comment: @reuns In my question there is no ideal $\mathfrak b$.

Comment: ?? $\mathfrak a= \lambda \mathfrak b^2$

Comment: That was just a repetition of the definition, not part of the question.

Comment: My $\mathfrak{b}$ is the one such that $\mathfrak a= \lambda \mathfrak b^2$ which by definition exists.

Answer (score 0):

I say Chebotarev but all you need is that for a non-trivial finite order Hecke character the Hecke L-function $L(s,\psi)$ is analytic and non-zero at $s=1$, and for the trivial Hecke character we get the Dedekind zeta function which has a simple pole.

With $Cl^+(K)$ the narrow class group, each $\psi\in Hom(Cl^+(K),\Bbb{C}^\times)$ is a Hecke character, and $$\prod_{\psi\in Hom(Cl^+(K),\Bbb{C}^\times)} L(s,\psi)^{\psi(\mathfrak{b})^{-1}} = \exp(|Cl^+(K)| \sum_{\mathfrak{p}^k, [\mathfrak{p}^k] =[\mathfrak{b}]}\frac{N(\mathfrak{p}^k)^{-s}}{k})$$ has a pole at $s=1$ (due to the trivial character), which implies that there are infinitely many primes in the narrow class $[\mathfrak{b}]$, whose square will be in the narrow class $[\mathfrak{a}]=[\lambda \mathfrak{b}^2]$.

Comment: Are you saying that for every $k \in \mathbb N$ there are infinitely many prime ideals $\mathfrak p$ such that $\mathfrak p^k$ represents a given narrow class?

Comment: No. I say that Infinitely many primes represent a given class. The Dirichlet series of prime powers with $k\ge 2$ is absolutely convergent and doesn't matter here. @principal-ideal-domain

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Still unclear to you? Did you see already the proof of Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions? It is exactly the same as my answer with $K$ and the Hecke characters $Hom(Cl^+(K),\Bbb{C}^\times)$ replaced by $\Bbb{Q}$ and the Dirichlet characters $Hom(\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}^\times,\Bbb{C}^\times)$

Comment: Yeah, it is still unclear to me. I saw the proof of Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions in Zagiers book "Zetafunktionen und quadratische Körper" many years ago. I looked up what Hecke characters are and how they are being used to form L series in Neukirch. But this actually confused me more than it helped me. There, Hecke characters are defined on the idèle class group instead on the narrow ideal class group.

Comment: However, I think I've found another way to solve my original problem which is related to the question I asked six days ago about the "Independence of fractional ideal for representation numbers in real quadratic number fields". I think I could prove a more general result using genus theory than the result stated there. No longer restriction to prime discriminant but instead of complete ideal invariance you have to stay in one genus.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Hecke characters, class field theory, analytic continuation of L-functions,  Artin L-functions, Chebotarev, the PNT and the RH, this is a difficult topic, sure, but it is essential in algebraic number theory. The narrow class group is a quotient of the idele class group so a narrow class group character gives a (continuous) idele class group character.